# Any way to export multiple playlists to m3u at once?

Tags: itunes, playlist

I can export a single playlist from iTunes to m3u format easily enough, but is there any way to do it en masse? I have about 40 playlists and it's exceedingly tedious to do it for all of them one at a time. I know you can dump the entire library database if you're just switching between macs but I use these all over the place. That library file is megabytes and megabytes and while I could conceivably reconstruct my playlists from the xml plist it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using **iTunes** by itself, I do not know of a way to export multiple **playlists** at the same time, as one can only select one **playlist** in the **Sidebar** at a time.

Normally to export a **playlist** in **iTunes** one would, e.g., select the *target* **playlist** in the **Sidebar** and then click: **File** > **Library** > **Export Playlist…**

This then brings up a **Save** *dialog box*, e.g.:

[image]

To semi-automate the process I assigned a *keyboard shortcut* of **⌘E** to the **Export Playlist…** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**, as shown the image below.

This allows me to easily bring up the **Save** *dialog box* without having to navigate the *menus*, and I can then just use the *keyboard* to easily walk through saving one **playlist** after the other.

It's easy to get into a rhythm, select the first **playlist**, then **⌘E** > **enter** > **down-arrow** > **⌘E** > **enter** > **down-arrow** > etc.

[image]

---

To further *semi-automate* the process, you can use a bit of **AppleScript** in **Script Editor**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
activate application "iTunes"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    repeat 1 times
        keystroke "e" using command down
        delay 0.5
        key code 36 # return key
        delay 0.5
        key code 125 # down-arrow key   
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell
```

Change `repeat 1 times` to the number of times you want it to repeat.

Then in **iTunes** select the first **playlist** on the **Sidebar** and then run the *script* from **Script Editor**.

This *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes you've already once selected the **Where:** and **Format:** and will use the *default names* in the **Save As:**, none of which are the same, and there are no **playlists** currently at the **Where:** that would interfere with the limited *example* **AppleScript** *code*. Otherwise, additional *coding* will be necessary.

If you want to use the *example* **AppleScript** *code* without assigning a *keyboard shortcut* for the **Export Playlist…** *command*, then in place of `keystroke "e" using command down` use:

```
    click menu item "Export Playlist…" of ¬
        menu "Library" of ¬
        menu item "Library" of ¬
        menu "File" of ¬
        menu bar item "File" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "iTunes"
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Keyboard shortcut idea is definitely helpful, that's way faster than using the trackpad.

Comment: @Jared Smith, I've added a bit of **AppleScript** to further _semi-automate_ the process.

Answer (score 0):

Here my applescript with some changes because the down-arrow key approach was not working very well.

```
activate application "Music"
delay 1

tell application "Music"
    set playlistArray to (get name of every playlist)

    # Foreach playlist...
    repeat with currPlaylist in playlistArray

        if ( (currPlaylist as string) is not equal to "Libreria" and (currPlaylist as string) is not equal to "Musica" ) then
            say currPlaylist
            tell application "Music"
                # Set the current playlist in the sidebar
                set the view of the front browser window to playlist (currPlaylist as string)
                delay 1

                # Start export
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke "e" using command down            # it's necessary to have set the shortcut CMD+E
                    delay 2                                     # delay in seconds
                    key code 36                                 # simulation return key
                    delay 2
                end tell

            end tell

            delay 0.5
        end if
        
    end repeat
end tell
```

To execute it from the terminal: `osascript ~/Desktop/automate_export_playlist.scpt`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a CLI utility to extract them from the Library.xml

https://github.com/jasmith79/playlistrs

If anyone else is interested. I used the custom solution mostly because it allowed me to tweak the path during processing for other devices and whether to use raw paths or file URLs.

Answer (score 0):

borrowing off of @suikoy

I wanted a way to have a select few playlists to export, not export every single playlist

I manually set the playlistArray to an array of strings.

```
log "--- Start Playlist Export ---"

activate application "Music"
delay 1

tell application "Music"
    set playlistArray to {"bangersonly", "playlist2", "playlist3"}
    log "Selected Playlists"
    log playlistArray
    set allPlaylistArray to (get name of every playlist)
    log "All Playlists"
    log allPlaylistArray
    
    # Foreach playlist...
    repeat with currPlaylist in playlistArray
        
        if playlistArray contains currPlaylist then
            say currPlaylist
            tell application "Music"
                # Set the current playlist in the sidebar
                set the view of the front browser window to playlist (currPlaylist as string)
                delay 1
                
                # Start export
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke "e" using command down # it's necessary to have set the shortcut CMD+E
                    delay 2 # delay in seconds
                    key code 36 # simulation return key
                    delay 2
                end tell
                
            end tell
            
            delay 0.5
        end if
        
    end repeat
end tell

log "--- Playlist Export Complete ---"
```

### English edits

Libreria = Library
Musica = Music